# Azure B2C - SAML ClaimsProvider downstream - inject an assertion or claim

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

What we like to do:

- User hits B2C login page, with a custom query string
- B2C takes the value of that querystring, inserts it in the SAML request to the downstream SAML IdP

Using custom policies, what's the correct way to inject the field into the SAML request? I can take the querystring value and return it as a claim in a JWT via way of an output claim, like so:
`<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="testquerystring" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:testqs}" />`

But that's just part of the relyingparty config in the user journey...the value never leaves B2C. We'd like to take the `testqs` value and send to our downstream IdP for them to do things with. Cheers.

Tristan

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft said it isn't possible right now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, but where in the provided link does it specifically say that it's not possible? I've been referencing this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#non-protocol-parameters - which is how I got the querystring to work in the first place...

Comment: Because there's nothing about SAML protocol. Only OIDC and OATUH2 are supported